# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an Android app with a login and register functionality. Whenever I run the app, the login page renders, and when I click on the create account button, it takes me to the register page as it should. After I fill in the blanks and I click on the register button, the app crashes. I used the debugger, and went through the same process, and I noticed an error message saying "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText.getText()' on a null object reference". What could be the root of this problem?

Here is my code:

activity_registration.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Registration">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutFirstName"
        android:layout_width="238dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:hint="@string/first_name"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColorHint="#757575"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextFirstName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/first_name"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutLastName"
        android:layout_width="238dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:hint="@string/last_name"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColorHint="#757575"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayoutFirstName">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextLastName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/last_name"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutEmail"
        android:layout_width="238dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColorHint="#757575"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayoutLastName">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutNewUsername"
        android:layout_width="238dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:hint="@string/new_username"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColorHint="#757575"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayoutEmail">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextNewUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutNewPassword"
        android:layout_width="238dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/new_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColorHint="#757575"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayoutNewUsername">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextNewPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutConfirmPassword"
        android:layout_width="238dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/confirm_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColorHint="#757575"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayoutNewPassword">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextConfirmPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/confirm_password"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newRegistration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/register"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayoutConfirmPassword" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Registration.java

```
    package com.zybooks.event_tracking;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final AppCompatActivity activity = Registration.this;
    // Field variables
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutFirstName, textInputLayoutLastName, textInputLayoutEmail, textInputLayoutUsername, textInputLayoutPassword, textInputLayoutConfirmPassword;
    TextInputEditText textInputEditTextFirstName, textInputEditTextLastName, textInputEditTextEmail, textInputEditTextUsername, textInputEditTextPassword, textInputEditTextConfirmPassword;
    Button register;
    InputValidation inputValidation;
    Database database;
    UserModel user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        setupUI();
        setupListeners();
        initObjects();
    }
    // initialize views
    private void setupUI() {


        textInputLayoutFirstName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutFirstName);
        textInputLayoutLastName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutLastName);
        textInputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutEmail);
        textInputLayoutUsername = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutUsername);
        textInputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutPassword);
        textInputLayoutConfirmPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutConfirmPassword);

        register = findViewById(R.id.newRegistration);
    }
    // initialize listeners
    private void setupListeners() {
        register.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // initialize objects to be used
    private void initObjects() {
        inputValidation = new InputValidation(activity);
        database = new Database(activity);
        user = new UserModel();
    }

    // listen the click the view
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.newRegistration) {
            postDataToSQLite();
        }
    }
    // validate the input text fields and post data to SQLite
    private void postDataToSQLite() {
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextFirstName, textInputLayoutFirstName, getString(R.string.error_message_name))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextLastName, textInputLayoutLastName, getString(R.string.error_message_name))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextEmail(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextUsername, textInputLayoutUsername, getString(R.string.error_message_username))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextPassword, textInputLayoutPassword, getString(R.string.error_message_password))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextMatches(textInputEditTextPassword, textInputEditTextConfirmPassword,
                textInputLayoutConfirmPassword, getString(R.string.error_password_match))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!database.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim())) {
            user.setFirstName(textInputEditTextFirstName.getText().toString().trim());
            user.setLastName(textInputEditTextLastName.getText().toString().trim());
            user.setEmail(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
            user.setUsername(textInputEditTextUsername.getText().toString().trim());
            user.setPassword(textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim());
            database.addUser(user);

            Intent g = new Intent(Registration.this, Grid.class);
            startActivity(g);
            emptyInputEditText();
            //we close this activity
            this.finish();
        } else {
            // Toast to show success message that record is wrong
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong email or password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
    }
    // empty all input edit text
    private void emptyInputEditText() {
        textInputEditTextFirstName.setText(null);
        textInputEditTextLastName.setText(null);
        textInputEditTextEmail.setText(null);
        textInputEditTextUsername.setText(null);
        textInputEditTextPassword.setText(null);
        textInputEditTextConfirmPassword.setText(null);
    }
}
```

Database.java

```
    package com.zybooks.event_tracking;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "EventManager.db";

    // User table name
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    // User table columns names
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_FIRST_NAME = "user_first_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_LAST_NAME = "user_last_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_USERNAME = "user_username";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";

    // create table sql query
    private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_USER_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_USER_LAST_NAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_USER_USERNAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";

    // drop table sql query
    private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;

    // Constructor
    public Database (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // Drop User Table if exist
        db.execSQL((DROP_USER_TABLE));

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    // Create user record
    public void addUser (UserModel user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_FIRST_NAME, user.getFirstName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_LAST_NAME, user.getLastName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_USERNAME, user.getUsername());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    // Fetch all user and return the list of user records
    public List<UserModel> getAllUser() {
        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID,
                COLUMN_USER_FIRST_NAME,
                COLUMN_USER_LAST_NAME,
                COLUMN_USER_EMAIL,
                COLUMN_USER_USERNAME,
                COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD
        };
        // sorting orders
        String sortOrder =
                COLUMN_USER_FIRST_NAME + " ASC";
        List<UserModel> userList = new ArrayList<UserModel>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // query the user table
        /**
         * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
         * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
         * SELECT user_id,user_first_name,user_last_name,user_email,user_username,user_password FROM user ORDER BY user_name;
         */
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, // Table to query
                columns,    //columns to return
                null,       //columns for the WHERE clause
                null,       //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,       //group the rows
                null,       //filter by row groups
                sortOrder); //The sort order

        // Traversing through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                UserModel user = new UserModel();
                user.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_USER_ID))));
                user.setFirstName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_USER_FIRST_NAME)));
                user.setLastName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_USER_LAST_NAME)));
                user.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL)));
                user.setUsername(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_USER_USERNAME)));
                user.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // return user list
        return userList;
    }

    // Update user record
    public void updateUser (UserModel user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_USERNAME, user.getUsername());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

        // updating row
        db.update(TABLE_USER, values, COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(user.getId())});
        db.close();
    }

    // Delete user record
    public void deleteUser(UserModel user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // delete user record by id
        db.delete(TABLE_USER, COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(user.getId())});
        db.close();
    }

    // Check if user exist or not
    public boolean checkUser(String username) {
        //array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // selection criteria
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_USERNAME + " = ?";

        // selection argument
        String[] selectionArgs = {username};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
                columns,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null);
        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if (cursorCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean checkUser(String username, String password) {
        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        // selection criteria
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_USERNAME + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " = ?";

        // selection arguments
        String[] selectionArgs = {username, password};

        // query user table with conditions
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
                columns,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        if (cursorCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize any of your `TextInputEditText` field variables (6) - they will be null if not initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this set of code to my Registration.java file solved my problem.

```
 textInputEditTextFirstName = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextFirstName);
    textInputEditTextLastName = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextLastName);
    textInputEditTextEmail = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextEmail);
    textInputEditTextUsername = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextNewUsername);
    textInputEditTextPassword = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextNewPassword);
    textInputEditTextConfirmPassword = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextConfirmPassword);
```